# What denominations consider Apocrypha to be heretical?

Tags: denomination-survey, canon, heresy, apocrypha

Over several years I have asked several pastors and preachers of differing denominations to comment on some books considered to be Apocrypha. Most generally my question was ignored, but on a couple of occasions I was told that they were heretical.  In the 1611 edition of the King James they included several books called the Apocrypha, and some of those books have become a part of the Catholic canon. However; some books have been rejected by both Catholics and Protestants.

I am not questioning why or even why not they are accepted or rejected; only which books are considered Heretical and the reasons they are. I am curious to know what denominations hold that opinion of the Apocrypha and if it extends to all books or to only certain books.

Please indicate which denomination you are representing and the basis for your answer (I.E. doctrine, common acceptance, and so on).

Comment: It would help to specify which of the Apocrypha you're speaking of. Just the seven books included in Catholic but not in Protestant canon? Or others as well (e.g. those included in the Eastern Orthodox canon but not the Catholic canon)?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "believe the books to be heretical"?  There's a difference between believing something is "heretical" and "not inspired".   Many groups believe that the **books themselves are not inspired***, and because the books aren't inspired,  the ***doctrines that are drawn from the books are heretical***.  I'm not sure I know of any group that considers any of the *books themselves* to be heretical, just the doctrines that are rooted in the books.

Comment: Even Catholics draw some traditions from apocrypha (non-deuterocanonical).

Comment: @DickHarfield  Of course I am aware that there are books in the canon of the Catholic church which are not a part of the Protestant canon, and it is not those books I question, but  a copy of the 1611 King James version with the  Apocrypha gives several other books not included in either canon.

Comment: @MattGutting  see my edited version.

Comment: @David If the doctrines drawn from the books is heretical why would the book not be heretical?

Comment: @BYE No, I was talking about books that even the Catholic Church views as apocrypha .  One tradition that comes to mind, is that Joachim and Anne were the parents of Mary: this first appears in the apocryphal Gospel of James, but the Church does not regard it as heretical.

Comment: I do not believe there is anything in the KJV Old Testament apocrypha (Macabees, Esdras, Baruch, etc.) that is considered heretical by most Christians. However I believe much of the  New Testament apocrypha would be considered heretical. For instance the Gospel of Thomas is gnostic, the Gospel of Peter is Docetist, and so on. But some apocryphal books were rejected for other reasons, and probably would not be considered heretical, e.g. the Didache, the Gospel of James, and others.

Comment: @anonymous This does not answer my question. I asked for Denominations that consider Apocrypha heretical, not what books.

Comment: @BYE yes I know it does not answer your question which is why I posted it as a comment instead of an answer ; ) But I thought it would be a helpful observation for looking into the question. Personally though, I doubt most denominations have any official position on which apocryphal books are heretical and which are not. Instead they probably say something like in Norman Wise's answer along the lines of "only these 66 books are inspired and the rest are merely human writings." This would leave open the question whether each particular human writing is heretical or contains heretical teachings.

Answer (score 2):

As a Presbyterian coming from a reformed tradition, we would see the canon of scripture defined by the Hebrew Bible which is received by the Jewish community as the books which represent the "rule of faith" for the community  In addition, we accept the 27 Greek books called the New Testament as the books inspired by God to represent the unchanging teaching of the Apostles.  (http://www.bible-researcher.com/bruce1.html for discussion of the development of the New Testament can)

The Westminister Confession of Faith which is the doctrinal standard for Presbyterians state:

III. The books commonly called Apocrypha, not being of divine inspiration, are no part of the Canon of Scripture; and, therefore, are of no authority in the Church of God, nor to be any otherwise approved, or made use of, than other human writings. (Chapter One)

So while these books are not seen as being part of inspired scripture they may as any human books have useful information in them.  Only when statements in these books would make statements contrary to the Hebrew Bible and New Testament would such statements be considered "heretical."  We would not see the whole books as such.

These books, for instance, may provide useful historical information on the thinking of the Jews from the end of the Hebrew Bible to the beginning of the New ( a period of about 400 years. )  So we would not see the entire books as heretical.